# Unknown eiffel syntax error

Tags: variables, eiffel

I am a beginner in Eiffel programming and I just try to create variable and I get an error,heres my code:

```
class
    APPL
create
    make
        local         
            v1:BOOLEAN
            v2:BOOLEAN
            v3:BOOLEAN

        do
            io.putstring ("test")
        end

end
```

I keep getting a "syntax error" on the "local" word...without any details.I'm pretty sure its something really stupid but cant manage to find it.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The create clause only lists the names of the features that are considered constructors. You need to implement them in the feature clause:

```
class
    APPL

create
    make

feature
    make
        local         
            v1: BOOLEAN
            v2: BOOLEAN
            v3: BOOLEAN
        do
            io.putstring("test")
        end

end
```